# sed error unterminated substitute pattern for new line text

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I am writing a script to add new dependencies to the watch list. I am putting a placeholder to know where to add the text, for eg

```
assets = [
  "../../new_app/assets"
  # [[NEW_APP_ADD_ASSETS]]
]
```

It is simple to replace just the place holder but my problem is to add comma in the previous line.

that can be done if I search and replace

```
"
# [[NEW_APP_ADD_ASSETS]]
```

ie `"\n # [[NEW_APP_ADD_ASSETS]]`

I am not able to search for the new line.

One of the solutions I found for adding a new line was

```
sed -i '' 's/newline/line one\
line two/' filename.txt
```

But when same way done for the search string it returns `:unterminated substitute pattern`

```
sed -i '' s/'assets\"\
   #'/'some new text'/ filename.txt
```

PS: I writing on macos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed works on a line-by-line base, hence it becomes tricky to add the coma to the previous line as that line has already been processed. It is possible, but the `sed` syntax quickly becomes messy.

To be a bit more specific:

> In default operation, **sed cyclically shall append a line of input, less its terminating <newline> character, into the pattern space**. Reading from input shall be skipped if a <newline> was in the pattern space prior to a `D` command ending the previous cycle. The sed utility shall then apply in sequence all commands whose addresses select that pattern space, until a command starts the next cycle or quits. If no commands explicitly started a new cycle, then **at the end of the script the pattern space shall be copied to standard output** (except when `-n` is specified) **and the pattern space shall be deleted**. Whenever the pattern space is written to standard output or a named file, sed shall immediately follow it with a <newline>.

In short, if you do not manipulate the *pattern space*, you cannot process <newline> characters as they just do not appear!

And even shorter, if you only use the substitute command, sed only processes one line at a time!

This is also why you suffer from `: unterminated substitute pattern`. You are searching for a newline character, but as sed just reads one line at a time, it just does not find it and it also does not expect it. The error will vanish if you replace your newline with the symbols `\n`.

```
sed -i '' s/'assets\"\n   #'/'some new text'/ filename.txt
```

A better way to achieve your goals would be to make use of `awk`. It is a bit more readable:

```
awk '/# [[NEW_APP_ADD_ASSETS]]/{ print t","; t="line1\nline2"; next }
     { print t; t=$0 }
     END{ print t }' <file>
```